# How to Handle Exception Occured In Web method which Is Called In a Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, webmethod

I'm calling a web method ajax call which returns a value say "Completed". In that web method whenever  exception occurs, it is not returning any value and I am not able to throw the message about the exception to the user. What should I do?

Comment: What tools are you using? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

If you could show us some could that would help :)

Maybe you could try, catch the expected Exception and return a string value other than "Completed" and could use this value to tell the user what when wrong.

Suppose that the Ajax call this method :

```
public string Test(){
     string ab1 = "ab1";
     try{
         int.Parse(ab1);
     }
     catch
     {
         return "Error";
     }
     return "Completed";
}
```

Something like that, I wrote it on the fly, maybe there are mistakes, just tell me, it was just to present my idea. And in your javascript, upon receiving "Error" you could warn the user something went wrong.

Comment: Hiee David , Actually I am trying  to send mail  in try  block of execution of stored proc .In that Try Block Again A nested Try Catch Block Is there which Catch execeptions occured In mail sending. And when There is an exception in mail sending then that web method is mot returning anything .